# Type mismatch: cannot convert from IntStream to int

Tags: java, java-8

I'm facing a problem when compiling this code as below:

```
int[][] result = Arrays.stream(board)
            .map(r -> IntStream.range(0, board[0].length)
                    .map(i -> IntStream.range(0, board.length).map(j -> decideAliveOrDied(i, j, board)))
                    .toArray())
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

The **board** is the input matrix where we can do some transformation. The method **decideAliveOrDied(int i, int j, int [][] board)** transform each input matrix's cell to another cell for a given row index i, column index j and matrix board. The **result** matrix is the output of the whole modification on **board** matrix.

For further info that's my method **decideAliveOrDied**:

```
public int decideAliveOrDied(int i, int j, int[][] board) {
        int result = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> list = getNeighbors(i, j, board[0].length, board.length, board);
        int numberOfLiveCell = (int) list.stream().filter(number -> number == 1).count();
        if (board[i][j] == 1 && numberOfLiveCell < 2) {
            result = 0;
        }
        if (board[i][j] == 1 && (numberOfLiveCell == 2 || numberOfLiveCell == 3)) {
            result = 1;
        }
        if (board[i][j] == 1 && numberOfLiveCell > 3) {
            result = 0;
        }
        if (board[i][j] == 0 && numberOfLiveCell == 3) {
            result = 1;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But I get a compilation error as detailed below:

```
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from IntStream to int
- The method map(IntUnaryOperator) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments ((<no 
     type> j) -> {})
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you post the definition of `decideAliveOrDied`?

Comment: @MarkoPacak check my edited post.

Comment: Three Stream operations are one too much, unless you truly have a three dimensional structure. But the fact that you are not using `r` anywhere says, you don’t have.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to guess what you are trying to achieve. As far as I've understood, your code can be reduced to:

```
int[][] finalBoard = new int[board.length][board[0].length];

for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        int result = decideAliveOrDied(i, j, board);    
        finalBoard[i][j] = result;
    }
}
```

You **don't necessarily** have to always use streams. Especially if you end up having three nested `map`s.

Answer (score 2):

Really not sure that stream api is good solution here. But you are mapping `IntStream` to another stream. Use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) for that:

```
....
.map(r -> IntStream.range(0, board[0].length)
        .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, board.length).map(j -> decideAliveOrDied(i, j, board)))
        .toArray())
....
```